# jquery: Can you string find selectors together

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm am trying to write some special validating code for a client.  I want to string several selectors together in the find function in jquery is this possible?

I am trying to say for example, in the fieldsets that are currently visible, find all the input fields with type=text and that have the class "-required", also find all the textarea field that also have the class "-required".

I am trying this, but it's not working, it only picks the Textarea fields

```
var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible')
.find('input[type="text", class*="-required",textarea[class*="-required"]')
.filter(function()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but not in the manner that you're attempting

```
.find('input[type="text"][class*="-required"],textarea[class*="-required"]')
```

To get the "and" behavior, we use two separate "attribute" selectors on the same element selector.

Then we use the `,` multiple selector to get the "or" behavior for the `textarea`.

I'm also assuming that `-required` is part of a class name, and not the entire thing. Some HTML reference would be helpful.

Comment: I don't quite follow  - Could you supply and example please?

Comment: @user1176783: The example is in the answer. You can't share a single attribute selector, but you can apply 2 attribute selectors to `input`, so I did `input[type="text"][class*="-required"]`, which will require that the type is `"text"` and that its class contains `"-required"`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see it now - sorry about that - at first glance, it looked like my code.  THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @user1176783: You were close. Your selector was just a little malformed. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

```
var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible')
 .find('input[type="text"].-required, textarea.-required')....
```

You had a several mistakes:

- You didn't terminated the attribute selector: `[type="text", ...`
- ,`class*=` is looking for the element of type class, (`<class>`)
- If you want a class selector, just prefix it with a dot.

---

**Update:**

```
var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible')
 .find('input[type="text"], textarea').filter(function(){
     return this.className.indexOf("-required") >= 0;
 });
```

---

Or as suggested by *@cliffs of insanity*:

```
var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible')
 .find('input[type="text"], textarea').filter('[class*="-required"]');
```

Comment: Hi Gdoron - i'm sorry this one won't work for me because I need to say "-require" is part of the class name vs specifically select a class name of -required.

Comment: @user1176783/ I updated with the way I would do that. the first option will work as long as one of those elements classes is `-required` if it can be `a-required` or `-requiredb` use the second option.

Comment: You have to return a value with the inner `filter` function.

Comment: +1 I think the filter is nicer than a long ugly selector. Another option would be `.filter('[class*="-required"]')`.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity. I added that option with your name on it. Though I prefer the function option, it must be faster and it's easier to read IMO.

Comment: I agree. The function will almost definitely be faster.